# Novel about Dreams and Mages in it who can travel to real worlds

Tags: story-identification, dreams

I am trying to find a novel that I read a long time back. Must be in young adult genre. It was about a realm which we can enter only through dreams. The world is composed entirely of things which we have dreamt of, past and present. It has kingdoms and the protagonist is a mage named Leonard Kite (not sure) and a woman who is in coma comes into this world.

The people in this dreamworld can enter the real world when they dream, though they are capable of remembering what happens in the real world. The first story indicates some kind of dark force that is forcing people in the real world to go into comas to use their dream power for evil.

Hopefully someone knows this. Any help is appreciated. I have tried regular google and it has not been helpful.

Comment: Made me think of *The Sandman*. I'll go read it again, just because.

Answer (score 5):

The book you are looking for is [*Mirror Dreams*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904233007) by Catherine Webb. Main character's name is **Leanan Kite**.

[This is](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11395404-dreamworld) like the vice versa of that I'll keep on searching because novel sounds awesome (and I kinda want to read it for myself).

I found it by scanning the 'Literature' section of the 'dream land' tropes page.

TVTropes Description:

> Catherine Webb's Mirror Duet is primarily set in the world of dreams
>   where people from Earth appear when they sleep, seeking their ultimate
>   dream. Each kingdom in this world caters to different dreamer tastes:
>   the main character controls a kingdom which specialises in storms.

Amazon Description:

> Every dream you've ever had, and every dream yet to come, exists in
>   the Kingdoms of the Void. Every nightmare, too. Because there has to
>   be balance—it's the rules. But the Lords of Nightkeep aren't big on
>   rules—only Conquest, Fear, and Eternal Darkness for All. It takes a
>   powerful wizard like Laenan Kite to keep them in check. But Kite has
>   other worries, and Nightkeep is growing strong. Its Lords hunger for
>   power. And they've turned their gaze towards earth.

Comment: FOUND IT! https://www.amazon.com/Mirror-Dreams-Leanan-Kite-Catherine/dp/1904233007

Comment: Bare URLs in the body don't look good. Also, while not exactly a requirement, you could add the synopsis from Amazon, just to speed up OP's recognition process.

Comment: Ah alright!. I'll also add the trope one. Sorry for that, and thank you for editing it!.

Comment: Wow!..Thank you....I guess its the same...have to buy it to check....Thank you so much..:)

Comment: @VinooGopalNair don't forget to accept the answer!